# How to enforce that the iText PageEvent.onStartPage() is called before content is written to the document

Tags: java, itext

Usually `onStartPage()` is called **before** any content is written.

In my use case its somehow invoked **after** some content is written to the new page.

What I do:

1. Create a `Paragraph` with some introduction
2. Create an Element with `setKeepTogether(true)`. This element is so big, that iText will put it on the next page (what is the correct behaviour).
3. Now the `onStartPage()` is called **after** the element is added to the new page.

I depend on this method because i need to add a small text like *continuation of xx* to the top of the page.

This example reproduces the behaviour:

```
public class Main {
    public static String someTompic = null;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A7);

        final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("text.pdf"));

        // This PageEventHelper should write a small text "Continuation: ..." at the beginning if
        // a PageBreak was forced by "keepTogether"
        writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEventHelper() {

            @Override
            public void onStartPage(final PdfWriter writer, final Document document) {
                try {
                    if (someTompic != null)
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Continuation: " + someTompic));
                }
                catch (final DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        document.open();

        // Now I add the introduction text
        document.add(new Paragraph("A nice \nIntroduction \nover some lines."));

        // Now I put my "huge" thing. If this breaks,
        // the first line of the new page should be Continuation of ...
        someTompic = "smth.";

        final Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("What is \nthe answer \nto life the \nuniverse and \neverything?\n\nThe Answer to \nthis question \nis:\n42");
        paragraph.setKeepTogether(true);
        document.add(paragraph);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

This Link shows the broken PDF: [PDF on Github](https://github.com/d0x/questions/blob/master/stackoverflowPlayground/src/main/java/itext/onstartpage/pagebreak/text.pdf?raw=true)

Comment: a) You are not expected to do any document changes during `onStartPage`. You may use it to retrieve certain state information for the time the page was started (e.g. current chapter at that time). b) You are not expected to add content to the `Document` instance in any `PdfPageEvent` method implementation. You may add to the direct `PdfWriter` content in `onEndPage`, though, e.g. some header at the top of the page, probably making use of the chapter information retrieved during `onStartPage`.

Comment: You are right. The doc says "do not use Document.add()"... Do you have an idea how to insert the "Continuation: ..." at the top of a page?

Comment: @mkl I linked this post to the question "How to append the text "Continuation of ..." at the new page, when an element got split by setkeepTogether(true)". Maybe you can help me there.

Comment: *Do you have an idea how to insert the "Continuation: ..." at the top of a page?* - As I hinted at in my former comment: Only use `onStartPage` to check whether "Continuation of ..." needs to be added, and store this in a variable of the `PdfPageEvent` implementation; then in `onEndPage` check that variable and if it is `true`, add "Continuation of ..." at the top of the page using `PdfWriter.getDirectContent`.

Comment: @mkl that could be an idea. But the problem is, that on the new page the paragraph used already the space right below the top margin. So there is no space left for *"Continuation: ..."* (or i have to write into the margin what looks not nice :().

Comment: *the paragraph used already the space right below the top margin.* - what about putting the "Continuation: ..." just above it?